# automatically login the user using windows form application?

Tags: .net, desktop-application

is it possible that when i start a windows form application , it automatically picks up the username and password from the credential entered at the starting of the windows and login the user automatically.

Comment: Login into what? Against what kind of userstore you want to validate the credentials?

Comment: the app has to be used in intranet. it will login using the credential and then i will use the app to interact with a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picking up password is never possible as it is a security threat.

Depending on the language your WinForms application is written in, there might be several methods to get the Username of the user currently logged in.

In C#, you can get it like this:

```
string username = Environment.UserName;
string domain = Environment.UserDomainName;
string fullyQualifiedUsername = domain + "\\" + username;
```

Once, you have the username, you can assume that the user is already authenticated as he is logged in to the machine.

Hence, you can then bypass ASP.NET Forms authentication by creating a custom page which "logs in" the user obtained above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Activities.Statements;

public partial class sso : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = Request["username"];
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, false);
    }
}
```

You can then call the page thus: http://localhost/sso/sso.aspx?username=Varun+Chatterji

DISCLAIMER: This is sample code and not meant for production. If you implement a "login" in this fashion using query string alone, you must secure the login by some form of authentication in sso.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can get Windows Password using any API.

Here is one link which may help you

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813834

Answer (score 0):

You can always check to see if you have a valid `WindowsIdentity`:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

WindowsIdentity currUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
if (currUser != null)
{
   string userName = currUser.Name;
}
```

but as the others also said: you won't be able to retrieve the password - never.

If you want to log in to SQL Server, you can define `Integrated Security=SSPI;` in your connection string and your current Windows identity will be used to login to SQL Server. No password needed for this.